# Android Asynctask return problems

Tags: android-asynctask, return-value

I am facing a problem in value 'return' in Asynctask class in doInBackground method. I am getting an error, about 'missing return statement in below code.

`public class ForecastNetwork extends AsyncTask {

```
    public final String TAG = ForecastNetwork.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;
```

// Will contain the raw JSON response as a string.
            String forecastJsonStr = null;

```
        try {
            // Construct the URL for the OpenWeatherMap query
            // Possible parameters are avaiable at OWM's forecast API page, at
            // http://openweathermap.org/API#forecast
            URL url = new URL("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?q=94043&mode=json&units=metric&cnt=7");

            // Create the request to OpenWeatherMap, and open the connection
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            urlConnection.connect();

            // Read the input stream into a String
            InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
            if (inputStream == null) {
                // Nothing to do.
                return null;
            }
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                // Since it's JSON, adding a newline isn't necessary (it won't affect parsing)
                // But it does make debugging a *lot* easier if you print out the completed
                // buffer for debugging.
                buffer.append(line + "\n");
            }

            if (buffer.length() == 0) {
                // Stream was empty.  No point in parsing.
                return null;
            }
            forecastJsonStr = buffer.toString();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error ", e);
            // If the code didn't successfully get the weather data, there's no point in attemping
            // to parse it.
            return null;
        } finally {
            if (urlConnection != null) {
                urlConnection.disconnect();
            }
            if (reader != null) {
                try {
                    reader.close();
                } catch (final IOException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Error closing stream", e);
                }
            }
        }


    }`
```

What Should I return at the end?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you forgot to return the processing result

```
    forecastJsonStr = buffer.toString();
    return forecastJsonStr;
```

Comment: Do I have to write at the end? Actually , i am doing an online course by Google developers held by udacity and they haven't done anything like it.

Comment: Would it matter , if I change to Result parameter i.e public class ForecastTask extends <Void,Void,Void> to  public class ForecastTask extends <Void,Void,String> ? Help me. I am really get narky.